# App where I can edit photos in a canvas so I can add a background color and some text

Tags: macos, photos

I have an image and I want create another image for the app store, something like the picture below. So I have a screenshot of my application, now I need to add some text on top of it, along with a nice color.

Currently I am just sending all my pictures to my Windows, in which I am using Paint to do the job. I am a bit frustrated about how hard this is on macOS. I am searching for a FREE program who can do such an easy job, but I am having a hard time. I tried Darkroom, Photos, Paint S, but they all are complicated and I don't see a canvas in which I can drag and drop an image.

Any suggestions on how to do this on macOS?

[image]

Comment: There's dozens of free sites that do this like [Screenshot.Pro](https://screenshots.pro/) and [Appure](https://screenshots.appure.io/). Do none of those work for you?

Comment: You may need to clarify whether you mean on top - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcJ44.jpg - or *above* - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsfrB.jpg The authors of each answer seem to have assumed opposing definitions.

Comment: @fsb both paid websites or you need to add an attribute in your app.

Comment: That's correct but using an attribute, like you probably already have for various code snippets being used, is a small concession for these images. Especially when considering the work-arounds to get a 3rd-party image app (or Windows) to make what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe use the FreeForm built-in app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple image editors tend not to be canvas-based at all, they are entirely image-based; so the canvas is always the same size as the image itself.

So, what appears at first glance to be a simple request is actually more complex than you'd think. More advanced editors such as Photoshop or Gimp can change the canvas size independently of the image size. Gimp is free, cross-platform.
Downloadable from https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ or there's a more Mac-like build maintained separately at https://www.partha.com [this is always slightly behind the official build versions as the author needs to wait for the official release first.]

You can then resize the canvas using Image menu → Canvas Size…

Full instructions at https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-resize.html

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. It is also nice that I can save the project and share it with others. Funny name though, reminds me of pulp fiction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Preview app, which has a few editing capabilities. While it doesn't have a canvas per se, you could just copy any image and select "New from Clipboard" (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and then Tools > Adjust Size to stretch your canvas to a desired size. Then select all (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit delete. Now you have kind of a canvas and can start pasting images, add text and simple objects, like squares and circles.

I've used your image, added a rectangle with both the same border and foreground to overlay the Dutch words and put the English words on top. It's probably not the right font.

Once you're done, you can select a rectangle around the final image, crop it (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and save it. Preview is quite versatile in this regard.

[image: Preview]

Comment: I've asked the OP for clarification as to what they mean by 'on top'. This method, as far as I can see, would only work for 'directly on the existing image' as opposed to 'outside of it'. See images above.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that wasn't clear. Both options, 'on top' or 'above', would work with Preview. I've only shown the 'on top' option. For the 'above' you'd take any image, stretch it to the desired width and height with Tools > Adjust Size and then would add the various parts to it.

Comment: I can't figure any way to increase the canvas size in Preview independently of the image size.

Comment: Open any image with Preview, then in the Tools > Adjust Size dialog (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVJIK.png) edit the size to the desired dimensions, then hit Cmd-A and delete. Now you have a canvas in the desired size and can start adding the other elements, eg. screenshots, text, shapes, to it. Admittedly it's a bit cumbersome, but also quick way to create an image without the need to attribute anyone.

Comment: This simply doesn't work for me. I can change the size, delete content, annotate just fine… but I cannot add any other image to it, all I get is an icon with PNG or JPG etc. No image.

Comment: Here are 3 images in sequence: Opened image from OP and a screen cap from my desktop (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvHpZ.png), changed size/dimensions of the original image, selected all, deleted all and put a white background on to show the new size. Then pasted the original image into it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/InNlw.png). Lastly, added the screen cap from my desktop to the new canvas and added some text and shape (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0DwP.png). This way I can gradually assemble a new image just with Preview. #photoshopforthepoor

Comment: Ah, I got it. Seems you can only copy.paste from within Preview. I hadn't tried that. Most graphics apps I use you can just copy the file on the desktop. OK, I got it to work… but I don't think I'll be swapping Photoshop for it anytime soon ;))

Comment: Agree, Photoshop (or Affinity Photo, which I use) is still somewhat superior. If you screenshoot something and have it sent to the clipboard, you can also use it in Preview btw.

Answer (score 0):

Short and Simple Anwer:

Paint X

https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/paint-x-paint-draw-and-edit/id668502966?mt=12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/336785)